What does invariant section in GNU FDL copyright note mean?
In a Polish translation of the book Free as In Freedom about Richard Stallman there is this copyright note:

Permission ts granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this document under the terms
of the GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.1 or any later version published
by the Free Software Foundation; with the Invariant Sections being no invariant sections,
with the Front-Cover Texts being no invariant sections, and with the Back-Cover texts
being no invariant sections. A copy of the license is included in Appendix C, GNU
Free Documentation License. All images are to be included vebatim when the document
is copied, distibuted, or modified under the terms of the GFDL.

What does it mean "Invariant Sections" in text:

with the Invariant Sections being no invariant sections,
with the Front-Cover Texts being no invariant sections, and with the Back-Cover texts
being no invariant sections.

The 2.0 version have different note:

Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this document
under the terms of the GNU Free Documentation License, Version
1.3 or any later version published by the Free Software Foundation;
with no Invariant Sections, no Front-Cover Texts, and no Back-Cover
Texts. A copy of the license is included in the section entitled “GNU
Free Documentation License.”

Are those two copyright notes the same?

"Invariant section" means "invariant section" as defined in Section 1 of the license. Is there something you don't understand in the definition in the license?

@PhilipKendall I was not able to check the website because Cert expired. I've emailed FSF with info about it. It seems that they bring it back.

@PhilipKendall English is not my native language, I understand nothing in this text.


What does it mean "Invariant Sections"

The GFDL license has the provision that the author can forbid anyone to make changes to certain sections of the book. Those sections are called Invariant Sections and must be mentioned as part of the license indication.
If a book has Invariant Sections, then anyone making changes to the book (including translations to a different language) must take over those named sections without changing them in any way. The book Free as In Freedom does not have any such Invariant Sections.

Are those two copyright notes the same?

Yes and no. The two license notices are the same with regards to the Invariant Sections you asked about in the rest of the question. The two license notices refer to different versions of the GFDL license (respectively version 1.1 and version 1.3). I have not researched to what extent those licenses differ, but they are different licenses.

Note that Invariant Sections are forbidden from being directly "about" the same subject matter as the rest of the work. The example used in the license is a mathematics textbook, whose invariant sections "may not explain any mathematics." They're meant to be used for things like forwards, appendices, and other such material, not for the main body of the work.

So what it mean for the cover of the book if there is "with no Invariant Sections, no Front-Cover Texts, and no Back-Cover Texts"? Is cover on Free license and can be reused? Or does it mean that cover is not included with the license in both licenses? I'm trying to understand the license, because someone upload Polish version of the cover to Wikimedia Commons as Open content.

@jcubic: "with no [X]" means "there are no [X]." In this case, there are no invariant sections, front-cover texts, or back-cover texts, so you can disregard the parts of the license that deal with those, as they are not applicable to the image you describe.
